# MUI Property 'palette' does not exist on type 'Theme'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using MUI with typescript. And I keep getting this error

> Property 'palette' does not exist on type 'Theme'.ts(2339)

Here is the code

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
}));
```

But when I `console.log` the `theme` variable, it displays an object with the `palette`property.

```
{palette:...}
```

Why is typescript showing this error, when the object has the properties? what type should I make the `theme` variable for the compiler to pass?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried to simlate your issue and i only could get this error if I import `styled` from `@mui/styles` or `@mui/styled-engine`.

Styled should be import from `@mui/material/styles`, as you can see [here](https://mui.com/system/styled/#import-path). So, the code will be like:

```js
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

Regarding the difference of the both imports, according to Mui docs:

**@mui/styled-engine:**

> @mui/styled-engine - a thin wrapper around emotion's styled() API, with the addition of few other required utilities, such as the <GlobalStyles /> component, the css and keyframe helpers, etc. This is the default.

* Basically it wont work with other `@mui` libraries, like `ThemeProvider`.

**@mui/material/styles:**

> All the MUI components are styled with this styled() utility. This utility is built on top of the styled() module of @mui/styled-engine and provides additional features.

And `styled` imported from `@mui/material/styles` use `styled` code from `@mui/styled-engine` as base, implementing features and making it possible to work and handle with other `@mui` librarys such as `ThemeProvider` and `createTheme`.

You can check the difference of both implementation below:

1. from [@mui/material/styles](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-styles/src/styled/styled.js#L22)
2. from [@mui/styled-engine](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-styled-engine/src/index.js#L3)

Comment: Isn't the recommended `styled` for MUI version 5.8.3 imported from `@mui/styled-engine`? What is the difference?

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error, but I am just using the theme created by createTheme() from @mui/material/styles.

I tried extending the module from @mui/material/styles but it didn't work.

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Theme {
    palette: Palette;
  }
}
```

it seems the module resolution I am using in typescript does not resolve the extend interface correctly from the types module:

```js
interface BaseTheme extends SystemTheme {
  mixins: Mixins;
  palette: Palette;
  shadows: Shadows;
  transitions: Transitions;
  typography: Typography;
  zIndex: ZIndex;
  unstable_strictMode?: boolean;
}

// shut off automatic exporting for the `BaseTheme` above
export {};

/*** Our [TypeScript guide on theme customization](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme) explains in detail how you would add custom properties.
     */

    export interface Theme extends BaseTheme {
      components?: Components<BaseTheme>;
      unstable_sx: (props: SxProps<Theme>) => CSSObject;
      unstable_sxConfig: SxConfig;
    }
```

So, it is not getting the properties from BaseTheme.

The solution was changing the type from tsconfig file from

```
"module": "ESNext"
```

to:

```
"module": "NodeNext"
```

weird, but it worked, although it messed up my global path resolution in imports:

```
@/components/somecomponents
```

so I decided to leave it with the eslint error